# PowerPoint not opening from Desktop app

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file, office-web-apps, powerpoint

I have a problem to open pptx from SharePoint Document Library modern view SharePoint online. When I click on the file nothing happens, where docs or docx and excel files opens from desktop app.

This is happening to only one user out of 20

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: Whether this issue occurs in all pptx files, all libraries, all site collections?

Comment: On all pptx files in all libraries, that to for not all users but certain users

Comment: What is the permission of these certain users?

Comment: User falls under member group